# Shutting down windows operating system using Java code

Tags: java

I'm trying the following Java code to shut down Windows operating system. I'm using **Microsoft Windows XP Professional version 2002, Service pack 3 with Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU** using Netbeans IDE 6.9.1.

```
package shutdownos;

import java.io.IOException;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException
    {
        String shutdownCommand="";
        String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name");

        if ("Linux".equals(operatingSystem) || "Mac OS X".equals(operatingSystem))
        {
            shutdownCommand = "shutdown -h now";
        }
        else if ("Windows".equals(operatingSystem))
        {
            shutdownCommand = "shutdown.exe -s -t 0";
        }
        else
        {
            //throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported operating system.");
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCommand);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

---

It throws the following exception in Java.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty command
```

The exception occurs on the following line in the above code.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCommand);
```

The second-last in the main() method. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at that line and see what shutdownCommand is. I don't think it's being set. Try uncommenting the throw exception. There is so many other things wrong with this code, but lets start there.

Comment: I modified this line in the above code `else if ("Windows".equals(operatingSystem))
` to have `else if ("Windows XP".equals(operatingSystem))` and windows shut down successfully.

Comment: Also note that you may not be allowed to run this command.  Your code should handle such a situation properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the wrong value of `os.name` -- whatever it is, it's not "Windows" and therefore the code runs through the `else` block where the variable `shudowncommand` is left as an empty string, which causes the "Empty command" exception. Do a `System.out.println(operatingSystem)` to see what value you should check for instead of "Windows".

It's probably something like "Windows NT", so if you replace the `.equals()` check by a `.startsWith()` check you should be set.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/) page, you seem to be using the wrong value for O/S names. If that is the case, your `shutdownCommand` string will remain empty, which will cause your program to pass an empty command, which conforms with the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

the program is skipping both the if statements, os.name would not be just Windows, it would be i think Windows XP or more, so replace that with starts with

```
else if (operatingSystem.startsWith("Windows")){

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no property "os.name" that is equal to "Windows". Did you mean to check for if the property contains "Windows"?. As far as I know all window os names have a quantifier such as "Windows 95", "Windows NT" etc.

Answer (score 1):

The shutdown command for windows os should be `shutdown -s -t 0`. try with this.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use this site to find out the possible values: [What os or arch value can I use?](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/os.html)

As others said, you should use [String.startsWith()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method.